# Overlap query on N:M association with Sequelize using MySQL dialect?

Tags: sequelize.js

Given the following Sequelize models:

```
models.Post.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
    through: models.PostTag,
    foreignKey: 'post_id',
    as: 'tags'
});

models.Tag.belongsToMany(models.Post, {
    through: models.PostTag,
    foreignKey: 'tag_id'
});
```

I am able to query for a post tagged with the tag having tag_id = 2 like this:

```
models.Post.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.Tag,
        as: 'tags',
        where: {
            tag_id: 2
        }
    }]
})
```

Now, I would like to query for all posts that have been tagged with all of the following tags(tag_id):  2, 5, 17, 87  (or any other set of tags).
I am using MySQL as DB dialect. It seems that some operators exists that might accomplish this ($overlap, $contains, $contained), but maybe these are PG specific?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. Sequelize v3.13.0.